# How to match cell value to cell format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, cell-format

I have cells that appear as `20-Feb`, `20-Mar`, `20-Apr`, etc, when you look at the sheet. When you click on the cell you can see in formula bar `2/20/2021`, `3/20/2021`, `4/20/2021`. I would like to copy and paste `20-Feb`, `20-Mar`, `20-Apr` as text it other sheet(cells). After pasting when you click on the cell in formula bar it should appear `20-Feb`, `20-Mar`, `20-Apr` as text. Is that possible in Excel?

Comment: What you see is not a formula but a date. Apparently the cells have a number format to display day and month. You can use the same format for the cells where you want to paste the value.

Comment: That is not what I want.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain why this is not an option.

Comment: It's pretty self-explanatory if you read the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve cannot by done with just copy and paste.

You want to convert a **date** data type to a **text** data type. That will require a formula that performs the conversion, for example

```
=Text(A1,"dd-mmm")
```

That result is text and can be copied and pasted with values only as text into another cell.

You need to make a decision whether this is about appearance or data type.

- Appearance can be totally controlled by the format of the cell.
- Data type cannot be changed from date to text with a copy/paste operation